# Communicating using Dragon12 board with xbee chip

Tags: xbee, codewarrior

So basically, me and a friend are using the Dragon12-Plus2 board for our class in school, and we are trying to get them to talk via Xbee chips. We have hooked one of them up, and simply need a bit of code to get the Xbee to talk with the board so we can make sure it's in correctly. We are writing in C using Freescale Codewarrior, and as much help as possible is appreciated, especially next steps such as when we hook up the other one, how to get the two to talk and test, etc. They should in theory already be set up as a point-to-point system, but we don't have much experience at this time. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the XBee modules with "AT mode" firmware, you should be able to use the serial port on the Dragon12-Plus2 board to communicate just as you would with a wired connection.

You'll need to configure both radios with the same PAN ID.  Make one a coordinator and the other a router.  On the coordinator, configure the `DH` and `DL` settings to match the `SH` and `SL` settings of the router.  You can keep the router's default configuration of using `0` for `DH` and `DL`, which tells it to send data to the coordinator.

Do your testing on a PC with a two terminal emulators so you can verify that data sent in on one comes out on the other and vice versa.

Here's an excellent guide from the Digi website on [Basic XBee ZB ZigBee (Series 2) Chat](http://examples.digi.com/get-started/basic-xbee-zb-zigbee-chat/) which provides more detail and a step-by-step guide for configuring the radios.